# Time picker giving unusual time format on android

Tags: java, android

I have used a time picker in my android project. In the onTimeChange method I did something like this:

```
@Override
    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        long PICK = ((hourOfDay * 60 * 60) + (minute * 60)) * 1000;
        String delegate = "hh:mm aaa";
        timemode = (String) DateFormat.format(delegate, PICK);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), timemode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

but when I toast it, its showing unusual time(6 hours diffrence), how to get the original time picked in the time picker?

Comment: `DateFormat.format` ?? what is `DateFormat` ... i'm sure that it isn't standard `java.text.DateFormat` since it has no static method `format` ...

Comment: @Selvin It's from the Android api: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html

Comment: @Jave ok, so there is written that `long inTimeInMillis` argument is GMT and he is GMT +6 ...

Comment: @Selvin yeah, seems like a probable cause for his problem.

Comment: Hey ReyJohn, dude I had posted the link for you. and Mainank Brahmbhatt gave you the  code  from my link itself (I mean, I had posted the link earlier). You marked his post as answer... I felt bad...

Comment: I just want a simple solution, can anyone provide?